# High side MOSFET driver with transformer

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, mosfet-driver, powermosfet, high-side

I am reading the application note " Fundamentals of MOSFET and IGBT Gate Driver Circuits" written by Texas Instrument.

In order to control High Side MOSFET, the application note suggests to use this kind of circuit :

[image]

Why I just cannot use this kind of circuit ?

[image]

It seems simpler from my point … But this is probably not the case ?

[image]

Thank you very much !

Comment: You appear to have drawn your circuit in LTspice, have you simulated it as well? In the real world your NMOS might be damaged by voltage spikes that are not suppressed by diodes (which are present in TI's schematic). In your schematic L2 and M2 will resonate after the slopes of the pulse. That resonance isn't damped like in TI's schematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are controlling the pulse width but not using a DC restore circuit, it will mean that at a high value of duty cycle, the peak voltage from the transformer will not be enough to properly turn on the MOSFET.

Fact: the output of a transformer **must have** an average value of 0 volts and if the original pulse shape is 10 volts for 90% of the time, it will become 1 volt for 90% of the time after passing through the transformer: -

[image]

This is a simple simulation that shows what I mean. The input to the transformer goes between 0 volts and +10 volts (blue trace). It is capacitively coupled (1 uF) to the transformer primary. The red trace is the output of the transformer into a 1 kohm load.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. By saying the output of a transformer must have an average value of 0V, you mean the average flux across the transformer should be constant ? Where does this assertions come from ? 

This explain why they use an

Comment: No, it’s a tad subtler than that. Induced voltage is due to rate of change of flux and so if the average output voltage wasn’t zero it would imply an ever increasing magnitude of flux and that ain’t possible by a long way.

Comment: It all comes from Faraday’s law of induction i.e. V equals N d(phi) by dt.

Comment: I agree with you ! Thank you !

Comment: Nevertheless, In the LTspice scheme, I m not able to understand why my transformer will not reset its flux … as during Toff I do not apply a voltage across the winding of L1. If during Ton I applied 9 V during 10% of the period, during Toff the voltage would be negative and equal to 1V during 90 % ? 

In any case, In a forward transformer the flux produced at the primary will be transfered directly to the secondary so the transformer will be reset during the same period (without considering that the permeability of the transformer is not infinite … ) :( :( :( :(

Comment: I didn't comment on the primary flux in my answer because the basic problem (even if you were adequately driving the primary) is that the secondary CANNOT produce an average voltage that is not zero. To understand why the primary does not reset its flux requires more analysis but, nevertheless, even if it did reset its flux correctly, the secondary will always produce an average value of zero volts.

Comment: I added a simulation that show that the average ouput is not equal to 0 ... Are you sur of what you saying ? Did I understand what you wanted to say ?

Comment: Now try it with a more reasonable input resistor and look at maybe the 100th or 1000th cycle. Or just look at the current flowing into the primary and ask yourself when that current is going to settle down.

Comment: My picture was my simulation output.

Comment: I will try to put in in equation tomorrow !

Comment: You don’t really need to if you think about it a little; the average voltage applied to the primary is not zero hence, the current ramps up during the pulse and remains static during the off part of the input cycle. Along comes the next pulse and the current ramps up a bit more................... bang!

Comment: I think this question and answer are probably done now so, formulate the next big question and ask a new one and give others a chance to throw in their twopenneth.

Comment: Ok I got it I though ... What it happens is when you set a voltage of 10 V (Ton) at the primary during 50% of the period and 0 V (Toff) at the primary during 50 % of the period. During the On time you set the transformer to the energy Eon. You have to release this energy during each cycle in order to do not see the magnetizing current walk and do not saturate the transformer. The only way to do it is to release 50 % of the energy during the on time at the secondary by applying 5V at the secondary and -5V during the off time to release the remaining 50% ! Do you agree ? and we ve got an AC out

Comment: I’d need to see a schematic. The devil is in the detail but I’d strongly urge you to raise a brand new question.